# Why does the following python digitSum code gives the wrong answer?

Tags: python-3.x, sum, digit

```
digitSum=0
n=222222222222222222222222222222
while n!=0:
    digitSum=digitSum+(n%10)
    n=int(n/10)
print(digitSum)
```

The output should be 60, whereas the output is 86.

Comment: Add a `print(n)` in your loop, you'll see what is happening: after the first division, `n=22222222222222223739180810240`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `a // b` for integer division, not `int(a / b)`.**

On the first iteration of your loop, your code is effectively doing `int(222222222222222222222222222222 / 10)`. This results in a floating point value which you expect to be `22222222222222222222222222222.2` but in reality is `22222222222222223739180810240.0` due to limitations in floating point precision. This value propagates to the next iteration of your algorithm, where it obviously causes your wrong answer.

On the other hand `//` in Python performs *integer division*, which results in the truncated result you want. Because Python has unlimited integer range, this will work correctly even with very large numbers. So `222222222222222222222222222222 // 10` correctly results in the same number with the last digit removed.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too.

```
digitSum=0
n=222222222222222222222222222222
stringValue = str(n)
length = len(stringValue)
digitSum = length * int(stringValue[0])
print(digitSum)
```